# Dividing an array into K subsets such that sum of all subsets is same using bitmasks+DP

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

So, this problem I dont have any clue how to solve it the problem statement is :

> Given a set S of N integers the task is decide if it is possible to
>   divide them into K non-empty subsets such that the sum of elements in
>   every of the K subsets is equal.

N can be at max 20. K can  be at max 8

The problem is to be solved specifically using DP+Bitmasks!

I cannot understand where to start ! As there are K sets to be maintained , I cannot take K states each representing some or the other!!

If I try taking the whole set as a state and K as the other, I have issues in creating a recurrent relation!

Can you help??

The link to original problem [Problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/SANSKAR)

Comment: Bitmasks? Hm. Sure (0 < ) `K` <= 8, not `K` = 8?

Comment: @greybeard Yes this is an online judge problem ! K can vary from 1 <=K<=8 . I have updated my question with a problem link just in case you want to check out!

Comment: (Yes, I prefer being given the source - just in case. E.g., to check whether this is an ongoing competition …)

Comment: @greybeard - It is from dec-14 ! Not a live contest!

Comment: Have you checked out the editorial? It's not excellent, but it conveys the basic idea and also has some code

Comment: @NiklasB. Actually I was getting WA again and again , i thought I was missing something in my DP . Eventually I have solved it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the working O(K*2^N*N) implementation in JavaScript. From the pseudo code https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/58420/sanskar-editorial

http://jsfiddle.net/d7q4o0nj/

```js
function equality(set, size, count) {
    if(size < count) { return false; }
    var total = set.reduce(function(p, c) { return p + c; }, 0);
    if((total % count) !== 0) { return false }
    var subsetTotal = total / count;
    var search = {0: true};
    var nextSearch = {};
    for(var i=0; i<count; i++) {
        for(var bits=0; bits < (1 << size); bits++){
            if(search[bits] !== true) { continue; }
            var sum = 0;
            for(var j=0; j < size; j++) {
                if((bits & (1 << j)) !== 0) { sum += set[j]; }
            }
            sum -= i * subsetTotal;
            for(var j=0; j < size; j++) {
                if((bits & (1 << j)) !== 0) { continue; }
                var testBits = bits | (1 << j);
                var tmpTotal = sum + set[j];
                if(tmpTotal == subsetTotal) { nextSearch[testBits] = true; }
                else if(tmpTotal < subsetTotal) { search[testBits] = true; }
            }            
        }
        search = nextSearch;
        nextSearch = {};
    }
    if(search[(1 << size) - 1] === true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(true, equality([1,2,3,1,2,3], 6, 2));
console.log(true, equality([1, 2, 4, 5, 6], 5, 3));
console.log(true, equality([10,20,10,20,10,20,10,20,10,20], 10, 5));
console.log(false, equality([1,2,4,5,7], 5, 3));
```

**EDIT** The algorithm finds all of the bitmasks (which represent subsets *bits*) that meet the criteria (having a sum *tmpTotal* less than or equal to the ideal subset sum *subsetTotal*). Repeating this process by the amount of subsets required *count*, you either have a bitmask where all *size* bits are set which means success or the test fails.

**EXAMPLE**

*set* = [1, 2, 1, 2]

*size* = 4

*count* = 2, we want to try to partition the set into 2 subsets

*subsetTotal* = (1+2+1+2) / 2 = 3

**Iteration 1:**

*search* = {0b: true, 1b: true, 10b: true, 100b: true, 1000b: true, 101b: true}

*nextSearch* = {11b: true, 1100b: true, 110b: true, 1001b: true }

**Iteration 2:**

*search* = {11b: true, 1100b: true, 110b: true, 1001b: true, 111b: true, 1101b: true }

*nextSearch* = {1111b: true}

**Final Check**

(1 << size) == 10000b, (1 << size) - 1 == 1111b

Since *nextSearch[ 1111b ]* exists we return success.

Comment: Well even I have solved it, I can accept your answer if you add a little explanation to it or may be  just copy editorial . Just in case link goes down!

Comment: @Shubhay - I added a short explaination and example.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem in O(N * 2^N), so the K is meaningless for the complexity.

First let me warn you about the corner case N < K with all the numbers being zero, in which the answer is "no".

The idea of my algorithm is the following. Assume we have computed the sum of each of the masks (that can be done in O(2^N)). We know that for each of the groups, the sum should be the total sum divided by K.

We can do a DP with masks in which the state is just a binary mask telling which numbers have been used. The key idea in removing the K from the algorithm complexity is noticing that if we know which numbers have been used, we know the sum so far, so we also know which group we are filling now (current sum / group sum). Then just try to select the next number for the group: it will be valid if we do not exceed the group expected sum.

You can check my C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

ll v[21 + 5];
ll sum[(1 << 21) + 5];
ll group_sum;
int n, k;

void compute_sums(int position, ll current_sum, int mask)
{
    if (position == -1)
    {
        sum[mask] = current_sum;
        return;
    }

    compute_sums(position - 1, current_sum, mask << 1);
    compute_sums(position - 1, current_sum + v[position], (mask << 1) + 1);
}

void solve_case()
{
    cin >> n >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cin >> v[i];

    memset(sum, 0, sizeof(sum));
    compute_sums(n - 1, 0, 0);

    group_sum = sum[(1 << n) - 1];
    if (group_sum % k != 0)
    {
        cout << "no" << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (group_sum == 0)
    {
        if (n >= k)
            cout << "yes" << endl;
        else
            cout << "no" << endl;
        return;
    }

    group_sum /= k;

    vector<int> M(1 << n, 0);
    M[0] = 1;
    for (int mask = 0; mask < (1 << n); ++mask)
    {
        if (M[mask])
        {
            int current_group = sum[mask] / group_sum;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                if ((mask >> i) & 1)
                    continue;
                if (sum[mask | (1 << i)] <= group_sum * (current_group + 1))
                    M[mask | (1 << i)] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (M[(1 << n) - 1])
        cout << "yes" << endl;
    else
        cout << "no" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int cases;
    cin >> cases;
    for (int z = 1; z <= cases; ++z)
        solve_case();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPD: I confused N and K with each other and my idea is true but not efficient.Efficient idea added at the end**

Assume that so far you've created k-1 subsets, and now you want to create the k-th subset. For creating the k-th subset, you need to be able to answer these two questions:

1- What should be the sum of elements of k-th subset?

2- Which elements have been used so far ?

Answering the first question is easy, the sum should be equal to sum of all elements divided by K, let's name it **subSum**.

For second question, we need to have the state of each element, used or not. Here we need to use bitmask idea.

Here's the dp recurrence:

dp[i][mask] = means is it possible to create i subsets with sum of each equals to **subSum**, using the elements which are 1(not used) in mask (in its bit representation), So dp[i][mask] is a boolean type.

> dp[i][mask] = OR(dp[i-1][mask2]) for all possible **mask2** states. **mask2** will be produced by converting some 1's of mask to 0's, i.e. those 1's that we want to be the elements of i-th subset.

For checking all possible mask2, you need to check all 2^n possible subsets of available 1's bits.Therefore, totaly, the time complexity will be O(N*(2^n)*(2^n)). In your problem is 20*2^8*2^8= 10*2^17 < 10^7 which can pass the time limit.

Obviously, for base case you have to handle dp[0][mask] on your own, without using the recurrence.Final answer is whether dp[K][2^N-1] is true or not.

**__UPD__**: For getting a better performance,before get into DP, you could preprocess all subsets with sum of **subSum**. Then, for calculating mask2, you just need to iterate over the preprocessed list, and see whether the AND operation of them with mask would result in the subset in the list or not.

**UPD2:**
For having an efficient solution, instead of finding proper mask2, we could use the fact that at each step, we know the sum of elements till that point. So we could add elements one by one into the mask, and whenever we had a sum which is divisible by **K** we could go to the next step for creating next subset.

if (sum of used elements of mask is divisible by K)

```
    dp[i][mask]= dp[i+1][mask];
```

else

```
    dp[i][mask]|=dp[i][mask ^(1<<i)] provided that i-th item is not used and can not exceed the current sum more than i*subSum.
```

Comment: Time complexity should be O(K* 2^N *2^N) which is 8*2^20*2^20, which is larger than the time limit

Comment: @PhamTrung, Yes, You're right, I confused K and N with each other. This is not efficient at all.